# How would I convert categorical variables from a dataset to numeric?

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R programming. In the dataset that I want to work, there are 3 categorical variables that I want to convert into (0's and 1's).

This is how I tried to do it, but it didn't change anything?

```
A = mydata$industry
A[which(A=="yes")] = 1
A[which(A=="no")] = 0
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you mind giving us more information, for example a sample of your data?

Comment: Nothing is changing because you are not assigning the output to any variable, in addition to other issues with your code.

Comment: Try: `mydata$industry <- ifelse(mydata$industry=="yes", 1, 0)`

Comment: @Hylda Great! I put it in an answer in case you want to mark the problem so others see it as solved.

Comment: Just using `check <- A == 'yes'` will yield a boolean vector equivalent to 0/1.  I.e. no `ifelse` required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
mydata$industry <- ifelse(mydata$industry=="yes", 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below with dummy data of `A`

```
A <- c("no", "yes", "no", "no", "yes")
```

such that

```
> as.integer(factor(A, labels = c("no", "yes"))) - 1
[1] 0 1 0 0 1
```